# Does anyone know how can I close LOG(INFO) info in tensorflow meta_optimizer.cc:334

Tags: tensorflow

When I do inference by tensorflow c++ library, I always got the info "I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:334] Starting optimization for grappler item: tf_graph", does any one know how to close this info?

Besides, I have tried `export TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL=X`, none of number X works. 
I am thinking the worst way that comment the source code `334:LOG(INFO) << "Starting optimization for grappler item: " << item.id;` and recompiling tensorflow library.

Thank you very much if you can provide any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about it, `export TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=4` solved this problem...

Answer (score 0):

So in TensorFlow, `TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL` and `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL` are different. In your case, you could try `export TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=2` (I think 1 is for INFO, 2 for WARNING ...)

You can also try `os.environ('TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL',2)` in Python.